# why cant emacs 24 find a custom theme I added?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, emacs24

My entire emacs setup is [here](https://github.com/metaperl/emacs)

I loaded my init-theme.el file [here](https://github.com/metaperl/emacs/blob/master/init/init.el#L14)

And supposedly that should make [the darkclean theme](https://github.com/metaperl/emacs/blob/master/themes/darkclean.el) available.

But when I type `M-x load-theme TAB` the darkclean theme is not listed.

How can I register it for Emacs 24?

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9472254/1232000) emacs 24 have own theming support.

Answer (score 11):

If you install themes via `elpa` / `package.el` you'll notice that you need to add each theme folder into your `custom-theme-load-path` - this is a bit of a pain to do manually, especially when you take into account upgrades will create a new folder, e.g. 0.1.0 -> 0.1.2 will be a new folder inside your `elpa` folder.

Assuming you've installed your elpa packages into `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` add this script to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(require 'dash)
(require 's)

(-each
   (-map
      (lambda (item)
      (format "~/.emacs.d/elpa/%s" item))
   (-filter
      (lambda (item) (s-contains? "theme" item))
      (directory-files "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")))
   (lambda (item)
      (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path item)))
```

You'll need `dash.el` and `s.el` (available from elpa.)

Comment: FYI using [el-get](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/el-get) doesn't require manually updating your load-paths. I've verified mine got updated automatically with `C-h v RET custom-theme-load-path`.

Comment: @TimS. many themes will add themselves to the `custom-theme-load-path` automatically when installed (most newer/well maintained ones will at least.).  The script above just adds those that don't.  There's nothing in the el-get source itself which appears to do anything with the `custom-theme-load-path`, go ahead and grep it.

Comment: yeah, what I meant to say was that many themes installed will auto-update the path, not el-get itself... my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[init-themes](https://github.com/metaperl/emacs/blob/master/init/init-themes.el) has commented out the load path.

I have this `(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")` and i think it found all my themes with `M-x load-theme`, `enter` then hit tab to see all the themes.

there was no search in the github for your repo, so i couldn't grep to see if you are doing it elsewhere.  Also is your darkclean compatible with a 24 theme?

Edit: 1

actually i thought of another debug technique to rule out it being darkclean vs setup.  put into your directory the 
[solarized theme](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized) and if you don't see it in your load-theme you know it's you and not a theme, as solarized worked for me this way on emacs 24.

I don't enjoy it, and prefer wombat actually.

Comment: here is darkclean.el - https://github.com/metaperl/emacs/blob/master/themes/darkclean.el

Comment: Thanks for this :D

Answer (score 4):

I m new to emacs and wanted to add some custom themes and create my own as well.

first add this

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
```

then add any new theme to that folder. 
This first did not work and when i used load-theme  the themes in ~/.emacs.d/thems where not loaded.

the documentation says:

> Each theme file is named THEME-theme.el, where THEME is the theme
>   name.

so renaming darklean.el to darkclean-theme.el did the trick

Comment: Ahh did the trick! Thanks, was pulling my hair out why my theme couldn't be found until I saw you just had to add -theme to the end. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `custom-theme-directory` and then include the
sha256 hash in `custom-safe-themes` to remove the confirmation prompt
everytime you load it. To insert the sha256 hash, you can use the
`customize` interface, as then it is calculated for you. To enable the
theme, you will have to include it in `custom-enabled-themes`.

Below is an example from my setup:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; ...
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (dark-emacs)))
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("<SHA256 hash goes here>" default)))
 '(custom-theme-directory "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
)
```

To see my actual setup, take a look at the following links:

- [my custom file](https://github.com/suvayu/.emacs.d/blob/master/emacs-custom.el)
- [my dark theme](https://github.com/suvayu/.emacs.d/blob/master/themes/dark-emacs-theme.el)