# check if the theme is available before loading it

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-prelude

I am using `emacs` with the `prelude` configuration.
I changed the theme and it works fine, and I added it in the `preload directory` like so :

```
;; preload color theme
(setq prelude-theme 'my-theme)
```

I installed the theme via `prelude-require-packages`, but not in the `preload` folder (not sure if it is available that soon). Is there a way to programmatically check if the theme is available, to replace the previous line with something more safe, like :

```
;; just to get the idea
(when (is-available 'my-theme)
      (setq prelude-theme 'my-theme))
```

**Edit**
I tried :

```
;; preload color theme
(when (featurep 'my-theme)
  (setq prelude-theme 'my-theme))
```

But in this case I get the default theme, not 'my-theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load-theme` function uses `locate-file` to find theme files. This approach is based that code:

```
(if (locate-file (concat (symbol-name 'my-theme) "-theme.el")
                 custom-theme-load-path '("" "c"))
    (setq prelude-theme 'my-theme))
```

You can replace the entire `(concat ...)` construct with the theme filename string, which for this example would be `"my-theme-theme.el"`.

Comment: It is not working. Is it because my theme is in the `elpa` directory ?

Comment: Yes. Just add that directory to `custom-theme-load-path` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15381087/409228).

Comment: I'm a bit surprised though that I can load it using `M-x load-theme` but that it's not in my load-path ? But thanks I'll try that.