# "Cannot open load file, color-theme" error in emacs-24.1

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm a bit of a noob. So this question might seem a little bit annoying.

When I try and load the color-theme package into emacs thorough the instructions here: http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/ and here: http://emacswiki.org/?ColorTheme, I always get the error in quotes in the title.

It may be my init file, which is is an ~/emacs.el configuration. But I want to make sure.

Comment: Did you correctly add `color-theme` to your `load-path`?

    (add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/color-theme/")

Comment: you may look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9472367/1232000)

Comment: @wvxvw: That is incorrect, or at best misleading. `color-theme.el` and Emacs custom themes are not the same. Neither completely replaces the other. For one thing, switching among custom themes is very slow compared to color themes (instantaneous cycling). For another thing, you cannot undo the application of custom themes, in the sense of restoring the non-theme settings that were there before. If you "disable" a custom theme, that just leaves the last applied theme settings in place, rather than whatever was in place before applying any theme. But custom themes also have advantages.

Comment: @wvxvw: Agreed, about using what comes with `emacs -Q`, if it does what one wants. And they serve *some* of the same purposes, but each offers things the other does not.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect color-theme is not in your load path. I use color-theme too. Take a look at  init.el in my .emacs [here](https://github.com/rags/.emacs.d). You will several instance of how to load a third party library in emacs.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any of the previous answers solved your problem, but a nother issue may be that your config is in `~/emacs.el` whereas it should be in `~/.emacs.el` (the "`.el` suffix is optional, but the leading `.` is not).