# Cycle Custom Themes w/ emacs 24

Tags: emacs

I am currently using the new customtheme tool for emacs 24, and I'd like to be able to cycle through custom themes by hitting a key (such as f12).

The code below sounds like it does exactly what I want it to do, but it uses color-theme, which I don't want to do. I'm not familiar enough with Lisp yet to write this on my own or to convert from the old version to the new one. Is there anyone that can help me get the same functionality into emacs 24 using the new built in load-theme command?

Also, based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472254/setting-emacs-24-color-theme-from-emacs), I may need to call disable-theme with each call of the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the old solution using color-theme

```
(defun my-theme-set-default () ; Set the first row
  (interactive)
  (setq theme-current my-color-themes)
  (funcall (car theme-current)))

(defun my-describe-theme () ; Show the current theme
  (interactive)
  (message "%s" (car theme-current)))

; Set the next theme (fixed by Chris Webber - tanks)
(defun my-theme-cycle ()        
  (interactive)
  (setq theme-current (cdr theme-current))
  (if (null theme-current)
  (setq theme-current my-color-themes))
  (funcall (car theme-current))
  (message "%S" (car theme-current)))

(setq theme-current my-color-themes)
(setq color-theme-is-global nil) ; Initialization
(my-theme-set-default)
(global-set-key [f12] 'my-theme-cycle)
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here are **two** ready-made ways (using **Icicles** or **Do Re Mi**) to [**cycle Emacs custom themes**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme#toc3) (what you call color themes for Emacs 24, but they are custom themes, not color themes). The same page explains differences between color themes and custom themes.

Comment: I found that site, and the code I provided is pulled from there. It's the cycling by repeating a command code by JakubHozak.

The problem I'm running into, which may have been partly due to my misunderstanding of the names, is that his seems to be set up for color-themes, and I want to use custom-themes.

Comment: Corrected my post: four ways to cycle themes, but only two of them are for cycling **custom** themes: **Icicles** and **Do Re Mi**. No programming, no bother. Now it's up to you what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that's analogous to JakubHozak's code, but the switching isn't as fast as it is for color-themes. I don't understand why, entirely, but it seems to be caused by the difference between custom themes and color themes. Although if you restrict your cycling to themes that come with emacs, it seems to be much more bearable.

```
(setq my-themes (list 'tango 'solarized-dark 'solarized-light 'alect-dark)) ;;the themes I cycle among
(setq curr-theme my-themes)

(defun my-theme-cycle ()
    (interactive)
    (disable-theme (car curr-theme)) ;;Nee flickeringded to stop even worse
    (setq curr-theme (cdr curr-theme))
    (if (null curr-theme) (setq curr-theme my-themes))
    (load-theme (car curr-theme) t)
    (message "%s" (car curr-theme))
)

(global-set-key [f12] 'my-theme-cycle)
(setq curr-theme my-themes)
(load-theme (car curr-theme) t)
```